# ¿Ocultar una etiqueta y imagen cuando se presione el botón por segunda vez - PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto llamado PyDex es una app que permitirá buscar a un pokemon por su nombre o numero(Pokedex), bien mi problema llega cuando busco otro pokemon ya que no se como ocultar al anterior y queda uno arriba del otro, veanlo:

[image: Aquí el problema principal]

Lo que quiero es que al buscar otro Pokémon el anterior buscado desaparezca y así evitar que se coloque uno encima de otro.

aquí el código:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import pypokedex

class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #Cargamos el diseño
        uic.loadUi("designer.ui", self)

        #Aqui volvemos transparante la ventana
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        #Mostramos la ventana
        self.show()

        #botones
        self.buscar.clicked.connect(self.buscar_pokemon)


    def buscar_pokemon(self):

        #Si no hay nada en la entrada salta error
        if not self.insert_pokemon.text():
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error_entrada", "La entrada esta vacia!", QMessageBox.Ok)

        
        else:
            
            try:
                #Obtenemos el texto de la entrada y lo buscamos 
                pokemon = self.insert_pokemon.text()
                result = pypokedex.get(name=pokemon)

                #Creamos la etiqueta para el nombre del pokémon
                label_name = QLabel(self)
                label_name.setText(f"Nombre: {result.name}")
                label_name.move(86, 145)
                label_name.setHidden(False)

                #Creamos un objeto QPixmap para cargar la imagen
                image_pixmap = QPixmap("imagenes/pokemon/{:04d}".format(result.dex))

                #Y creamos un etiqueta que servira como la imagen
                image_pokemon = QLabel(self)
                image_pokemon.setPixmap(image_pixmap)
                image_pokemon.move(65, 200)
                image_pokemon.resize(200, 200)
                image_pokemon.setHidden(False)


            except:

                    QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error_busqueda", "Lo que se quiere buscar no es valido!", QMessageBox.Ok)




        
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ventana()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema, pero ¿por qué no limpiar el label antes de asignarle el nombre?:  label_name.clear() label_name.setText(f"Nombre: {result.name}")

Comment: Es una buena solución, pero ahora falta la imagen necesito eliminarla de algún modo para reemplazarla por el pokémon buscado recientemente

Comment: basicamente con el mismo concepto, también podrías asignar primero un texto vacío: image_pokemon.setText(""), buscá los métodos de las Qlabel y fijate cual se adapta más a tu necesidades.

Comment: Si tienes razón ya lo resolví, lo que hice fue crear dos etiquetas vacías en el designer y después insertarle el contenido así se reemplaza cuando busco otro Pokémon, muchísimas gracias :3